# Android Widget Onclick Button or Method or Method from another Activity?

Tags: android, methods, widget

I have a normal app with a widget(widget is an image button). When the widget is clicked I want to call a method from the `MainActivity` or a method from the `WidgetProvider` activity or attach an `onClick` to the widget which does something when I click it. I've read the documentation but the only thing I've found is to how to open an activity using a widget.

My WidgetProvider Activity code:

```js
package ali.simpleflaslight;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

      // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

      // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
      // to the button
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_layout);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton, pendingIntent);

      // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
  }
  public void someMethod() {
    //I want this method called when imagebutton is pressed.
  }
}
```

With the code above, clicking on the widget just displays my `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an action to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `<receiver><intent-filter>` tag:

```html
<action android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME.WIDGET_BUTTON" />
```

Declare:

```js
public static String WIDGET_BUTTON = "MY_PACKAGE_NAME.WIDGET_BUTTON";
```

In the `onUpdate()` method add a pending intent that matches the action:

```js
Intent intent = new Intent(WIDGET_BUTTON);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.MY_BUTTON_ID, pendingIntent);
```

Finally, in the onRecieve() method:

```js
 if (WIDGET_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
   //Your Code

 }
```